# Creating the Cayley table for $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times S_3$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, cayley-table

> Create the Cayley table for $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times S_3$

I know that the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
  + & 0 & 1 \\\hline
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}

And that the Cayley table of $S_3$ is

\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
  \cdot & e & (12) & (13) & (23) & (123) & (132) \\\hline
  e & e & (12) & (13) & (23) & (123) & (132) \\
  (12) & (12) & e & (132) & (123) & (23)  & (12) \\  
  (13) & (13) & (123) & e & (132) & (12) & (23) \\ 
  (23) & (23) & (132) & (123) & e & (13) & (12) \\
  (123) & (123) & (13) & (132) & (12) & (132) & e \\
  (132) & (132) & (23) & (12) & (13) & e & (123) \\
\end{array}

Though I do not know how to multiply a Cayley table by a Cayley table. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How would you multiply two elements in $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times S_3$?  This should give a good idea of how to construct the Cayley table.

Comment: I guess I would multiply an integer by a set permutation. For example, something like $0 \times (123)$ and $0 \times (23)$ to get the "sides" of the Cayley table.

Comment: No, multiplication in a direct product is element-wise.

Comment: It's going to be a "pretty big table" with $144$ entries.

Answer (score 1):

The operation which takes the Cayley tables of $G_1$ and $G_2$ and produces the Cayley table of $G_1\times G_2$ is sometimes called the Kronecker product, or tensor product, of matrices.  The elements of $G_1\times G_2$ are ordered pairs $(g_1,g_2)$, and the group operation is coordinatewise.

For your example, you're working with a permutation representation of $S_3$, so it might be convenient to also use a representation of ${\Bbb Z}_2$ as the two permutations $(4,5)$ and $\textrm{id}=(4)(5)$. The point is that the set $\{4,5\}$ is disjoint from $\{1,2,3\}$, so the action of $S_3$ on $\{1,2,3\}$ and ${\Bbb Z}_2$ on $\{4,5\}$ together generate a (faithful) action of $S_3\times{\Bbb Z}_2$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.